# Factoring values insertion in SQL

Tags: sql

Currently doing some SQL queries, I have been doing this one to have multiple products to a Product table. The thing is I realize that the 'Z' parameter is in every value inserted. Is there a way to factorize the code to avoid to repeat 3 times 'Z'?

```
insert into Product(maker, model, type) values 
('Z', 4003, 'Printer'),
('Z', 4001, 'PC'),
('Z', 4002, 'Laptop')
```

Comment: Yes, there is. But as long as the `maker` column consists of one-character values only, you won't save much memory. Anyway, the proper way to do this is with a second table, e.g. called `makers` (fields: maker_id, maker_name) that contains all makers. In the `product` table, you would have a `maker_id` column instead of `maker` and fill in the `maker_id` ot the respective maker. That way, you only save the maker names once instead of once for each row in the `product` table.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. To the OP, just don't insert that field, and afterwards set it for all entries with an update

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I don't Horse, I'm currently writing SQL lines on a SQL challenge website.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `INSERT .. SELECT` with a `CROSS JOIN`:

#### Some databases (like PostgreSQL, SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO product (maker, model, type)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'Z'
) z
CROSS JOIN (
  VALUES (4003, 'Printer'),
         (4001, 'PC'),
         (4002, 'Laptop')
) v
```

#### Other databases (like Oracle):

```
INSERT INTO product (maker, model, type)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'Z' FROM DUAL
) z
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 4003, 'Printer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4001, 'PC'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4002, 'Laptop'  FROM DUAL
) v
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pala_,
You could try...

```
insert into Product( model, type) values 
( 4003, 'Printer'),
( 4001, 'PC'),
( 4002, 'Laptop');

update Product
set maker = 'Z'
where maker is null;
```

Cheers 
Andrew

Comment: This solution would, for a certain time, set the maker value to null before it is updated, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `DEFAULT` constraint on `maker` field to make a default value for that while you are inserting new rows

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
    maker CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Z'
    ,model INT
    ,[type] VARCHAR(10)
)
```

For existing table try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Product
ADD CONSTRAINT df_Product_maker
DEFAULT 'Z' FOR maker
```

Now whenever you want to add a new row, you don't need to specify `maker`

```
INSERT INTO Product(model, [type]) VALUES   (4003, 'Printer')
                                            ,(4001, 'PC')
                                            ,(4002, 'Laptop')
```

Although you have ability to add a value for `maker` if you don't want to use `DEFAULT` value

```
INSERT INTO Product(maker, model, [type]) VALUES ('A', 4003, 'Printer')
```

My syntaxes are in SQL Server as you haven't mentioned the db you are using.